# how to get data where clause in another table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 table with relation . and i want to add where clause but this where clause is in another table . my table like this :

```
pencairan
+----+------------+------------+------------+
| id |  induk_id  |     qty    |    harga
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  1 |     1      |     10     |    1000
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  2 |     1      |     20     |    3000
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  3 |     3      |     10     |    1500
+----+------------+------------+------------+

induk_pencairan
+----+------------+------------+------------+
| id |  rek_id    |     name   |    address
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  1 |     1      |    somedata|    somedata
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  2 |     1      |    somedata|    somedata
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  3 |     3      |    somedata|    somedata
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  4 |     3      |    somedata|    somedata
+----+------------+------------+------------+
```

so i want to do like this :

```
$pencairan = IndukPencairan::with('turunan_belanja')->findOrFail($id);
if (!$pencairan)
abort(404);

$id = $pencairan->id;
$rek = $pencairan->rek_id;

$digunakan = Pencairan::with('induk_pencairan')
->where('induk_pencairan.rek_id' ,$rek)
->whereNotIn('induk_id ', [$id])->sum(DB::raw('harga*qty'));
```

but i get error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'induk_pencairan.rek_id' in 'where clause'
(SQL: select sum(harga*qty) as aggregate from `pencairan` where `induk_pencairan`.`rek_id` = 2 and `induk_id` not in (2))
```

can someone help this ??

#update my model on 2 table

on Pencairan models

```
 public function induk_pencairan()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\IndukPencairan::class ,'induk_id');
    
}
```

Comment: Can you include the actual raw SQL query for what your Laravel code is trying to do?

Comment: i cant explain this :( ,, i want to showing total (qtt  harga) but not in induk_id  , and this where clause is in relate table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have to [join](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins) them ...

```
  $digunakan = Pencairan::with('induk_pencairan')->join('pencairan','pencairan.induk_id','=','induk_pencairan.id')
            ->where('induk_pencairan.rek_id' ,$rek)
            ->whereNotIn('induk_id ', [$id])->sum(DB::raw('harga*qty'));
```

or you can use [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

```
 $digunakan = Pencairan::with('induk_pencairan')->whereHas('induk_pencairan',function ($query)use($rek)
        {
            $query->where('induk_pencairan.rek_id' ,$rek);
        })
            ->whereNotIn('induk_id ', [$id])->sum(DB::raw('harga*qty'));
```

Comment: i have error Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias

Comment: something wrong with the relations, please share your models

Comment: you can try using 'whereHas' as illustrated

Comment: i think wherehas is the solution but i still get error colomn not found . i dont know

Comment: 1054 Unknown column 'induk_id ' in 'where clause' (SQL: select sum(harga*qty) as aggregate from `pencairan` where exists (select * from `induk_pencairan` where `pencairan`.`indukpencairan_id` = `induk_pencairan`.`id` and `induk_pencairan`.`rek_id` = 2) and `induk_id ` not in (2))

Comment: i change induk_id with indukpencairan_id , but its still error colomn not found

Comment: induk_id must be in pencairan table, (like you said), if not , make sure of column name

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this

```
 $digunakan = Pencairan::with('induk_pencairan')
    ->whereHas('induk_pencairan', function($query) use ($rek) {
      $query->where('rek_id', $rek);
    })->whereNotIn('induk_id', [$id])->sum(DB::raw('harga*qty'));
```